# largest gcd of an array after a few operations

Tags: data-structures, python

consider we have `n` bags of random amounts of coins. given `k` extra coins, the question is to find the largest gcd that can be obtained by adding these coins to any bag( all the `k` coins may not go in one bag and not all the coins are necessarily added)

input consists of the number of bags followed by `k`( number of extra coins ) and the number of coins in each bag in the next line. the output the the largest gcd.

example:

```
input:
3 3
3 4 2

output:
4
```

which can be obtained by adding one coin to the first and two coins to the third bag.

(all inputs are between 0 and 1000 and the time limit is 1 secs)

Comment: Tricky. Please post when you found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have n numbers then find the largest c such that n * (c-1) <= k. You can achieve gcd=c easily. For example n = 1000, k= 1,000,000 you increase every number by 1,000 so no matter what the numbers are you can make them all multiples of 1,001.

Find the largest d so that k is enough to increase every number at least to d. That’s an upper bound for the gcd, because the gcd cannot be larger than every number.

Then try whether each g from d downwards to c could be the gcd by checking how much each number needs increasing to make it a multiple of g, and stop if the total increase exceeds k.